# How do you implement a Highpass filter for the IPhone accelerometer?

Tags: iphone

I remember seeing the code for a Highpass filter a few days back somewhere in the samples, however I can't find it anywhere now! Could someone remember me where the Highpass filter implementation code was?

Or better yet post the algorithm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[From the idevkit.com forums:](http://idevkit.com/forums/tutorials-code-samples-sdk/171-accelerometer-high-pass-filter-incorrect-apple-code.html)

```
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
static UIAccelerationValue rollingX=0, rollingY=0, rollingZ=0;


- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    // Calculate low pass values

    rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    rollingY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    rollingZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

    // Subtract the low-pass value from the current value to get a simplified high-pass filter

    float accelX = acceleration.x - rollingX;
    float accelY = acceleration.y - rollingY;
    float accelZ = acceleration.z - rollingZ;

    // Use the acceleration data.

}
```

Comment: The question is asking for high pass code, whereas this I believe is lowpass code. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Listings/AccelerometerGraph_AccelerometerFilter_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007410-AccelerometerGraph_AccelerometerFilter_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: @JamesMcMahon please read the comment in the code and carefully check its operation to understand how it works. It does use a low pass filter, but the output is high pass.

Comment: Ah my bad. I missed the subtraction at the end. Clarified some of the comments.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone wants to know, the highpass filter can be found in the [Accelerometer Graph sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link, i was looking for this one too. This is an example for adaptive / non adaptive highpass and lowpass filter: [Apple iOS Reference Library - AccelerometerGraph Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html)