# cocos2d :my rotation with the accelerometer is not smooth

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, accelerometer, smoothing

so I use the accelerometer in cocos2d to rotate my sprite but the rotation isn't smooth at all . I know that I have to use filter but I don't know how to integrate it in my code :

```
-(id) init
{
self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];

}

- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

ombreoeuf1.rotation = acceleration.y * 90 ;

}
```

sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Much better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142944/how-do-you-implement-a-highpass-filter-for-the-iphone-accelerometer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to implement a lowpass filter. Experiment a bit with `kFilteringFactor` until you get nice results.

```
// Declare an int `accelY` in your class interface and set it to 0 in init
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    float kFilteringFactor = 0.1;
    accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    ombreoeuf1.rotation = accelY * 90;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem : with kFilteringFactor = 0.1 There is a big delay. Indeed I turn my iphone and after 2 second my sprite rotates. I would like not to have delay and smooth rotation

Comment: Have you tried with a higher kFilteringFactor? Like 0.9 or so?

Comment: I have the same result, or it's shivering, trembling. So my problem is that I have the choice between a big delay and my sprite trembling .I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help You with the smoothness is to set the update interval to 30 fps instead of 60, so update your init to:

```
-(id) init 
{
    self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;

    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1.0/30];
}
```